# Como personalizar tela de login no Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Com as seguintes configurações de serviços abaixo consigo fazer o login no Twitter, Hotmail, Facebook.

**Observando que meu projeto no momento da criação habilitei a opção de login individual**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
        {
           twitterOptions.ConsumerKey = "#######";
           twitterOptions.ConsumerSecret = "#######";
            })
        .AddFacebook(facebookOptions => 
        {
           facebookOptions.AppId = "#######";
           facebookOptions.AppSecret = "#######";
         })
         .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
         {
            microsoftOptions.ClientId = "#######";
            microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "#######";
         });
```

Com às configurações de serviços realizadas:

- Quero criar uma página que será a inicial
- A página inicial terá somente buttons de logins através das redes sociais
- Exemplo da página que desejo fazer esta logo abaixo.

**A pergunta é:**

Como faço para configurar os botões com imagens das redes sociais dentro de uma página personalizada no Asp.Net Core 2.1 para a realização dos logins

No Asp.Net MVC tem a seguinte configuração dentro do **_ExternalLoginListPartial.cshtml**

```
 @using Microsoft.Owin.Security
 @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders) 
 {
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Faça login usando sua conta @p.Caption">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
 }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, porém você pode fazer o seguinte:

1. No projeto aberto, clique com o botão direito nele, depois em Add e em seguida em New Scaffolded Item, conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Na nova tela, escolha Identity e depois as views Login e ExternalLogin, pronto, agora customize.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na verdade você precisa usar o SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync() para obter os schemas e depois utilizar no seus botões e fazer um submit para o ExternalLogin. Mas veja os arquivos gerados que acredito que fique fácil.